# Parameterized pipeline build jenkins always use last build parameters. How to fix this?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins pipeline with multibranch setup. I set a build parameter for "Build with parameters" using Jenkinsfile. Issue is it always picks up the previous build parameters. Here is the code:

```
properties([[$class: 'JobRestrictionProperty'],
      parameters([

      string(defaultValue: 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#build-parameters', description: 'File-Location', name: 'File_Location')

  ]), [$class: 'ThrottleJobProperty', categories: [], limitOneJobWithMatchingParams: false, maxConcurrentPerNode: 0, maxConcurrentTotal: 0, paramsToUseForLimit: '', throttleEnabled: false, throttleOption: 'project'], pipelineTriggers([])])
```

I am doing a reset of this variable(making it empty) after every run. But for the next build, it always picks the last one(which is empty), not the new one defined in the Jenkins file.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is by design, parametrized pipelines prompts for parameters only the first time and then use those parameters by default